# How to set up retry when the connection pool fails.

Tags: tomcat

I want to ask two questions in regards to the connection pool
1. Im getting java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException error Caused by: org.apache.derby.client.am.DisconnectException: .
Is there a way to retry the connection in the xml?

1. Am I using the latest derby driver? I heard that using a derby driver latest can solve the problem but I want to use the derby driver across the internet.

Here's my code for my connection pool first.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <Context privileged="true" reloadable="true">
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
    <Manager pathname=""/>
    <Resource name="jdbc/CSE" factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
              type="javax.sql.DataSource"
              driverClassName="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"
              url="jdbc:derby://indigo.cse.yorku.ca:9999/CSE"
              username="student" password="secret"/>    
    <ResourceLink global="jdbc/CSE" name="jdbc/EECS" type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
  </Context>
```

Answer (score 1):

Referring to [this](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html). I added below parameter:

- testOnBorrow="true"
- validationQuery="SELECT 1"
- removeAbandoned="true

```
 <Resource name="jdbc/CSE" factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
              driverClassName="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"
              url="jdbc:derby://indigo.cse.yorku.ca:9999/CSE"
              username="student" password="secret" testOnBorrow="true"
            validationQuery="SELECT 1"
            removeAbandoned="true"/>    
    <ResourceLink global="jdbc/CSE" name="jdbc/EECS" type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
```